# Getting value from a button tag

Tags: python, button, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to solve pagination extraction on a page using BeautifulSoup.

I've managed to get buttons with

```
soup.findAll('button', class_='SomeName')
```

would get me this

```
<button class="SomeName" data-page="2" type="button">2</button>, <button class="SomeName" data-page="3" type="button">3</button>, <button class="SomeName" data-page="4" type="button">4</button>, <button class="SomeName" data-page="5" type="button">5</button>, <button class="SomeName" data-page="6" type="button">6</button>, <button class="SomeName" data-page="7" type="button">7-12</button>
```

I would like to get a list of numbers

```
2
3
4
5
6
7-12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text between the button tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
html = '<button class="SomeName" data-page="2" type="button">2</button>, <button class="SomeName" data-page="3" type="button">3</button>, <button class="SomeName" data-page="4" type="button">4</button>, <button class="SomeName" data-page="5" type="button">5</button>, <button class="SomeName" data-page="6" type="button">6</button>, <button class="SomeName" data-page="7" type="button">7-12</button>'
result = [i.text for i in soup(html, 'html.parser').find_all('button')]
```

Output:

```
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7-12']
```

Comment: Just what I needed.
`data = [i.text for i in soup.findAll('button', class_='SomeName')]`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use css selectors

```
output = [button.text for button in soup.select('button.SomeName')]
```